# Checking CSRF with multiple gunicorn workers in Pyramid

Tags: ajax, csrf, pyramid, gunicorn, pylons

I'm using Pyramids for my web app, which requires an csrf check for each request. During ajax-calls the csrf-token is set into the header for each request. Everything works fine for **1 thread** with **1 worker**, but as soon as I enable multiple workers, worker 2 does't know the token from worker 1. How can they *share* the csrf tokens?

Greetings

production.ini for gunicorn:

```
[server:main] # GUNICORN
use = egg:gunicorn#main
bind = unix:/tmp/gunicorn.sock
workers = 2
threads = 1
preload = true
reload = true
accesslog = gunicorn_access.log
loglevel = info
```

In Pyramid I only set:

```
config.set_default_csrf_options(require_csrf=True)
```

My HTML-skeletion has:

```
<input type="hidden" id="hidden_csrf_token" name="csrf_token" value="${request.session.get_csrf_token()}">
```

And every ajax-request:

```
var csrf_token = $('#' + hiddenCSRFTokenId).val();
...
headers: {'X-CSRF-Token': csrf_token}
```

**Edit**: I'm using the *default* session factory like

```
session_factory = session_factory_from_settings(settings)
...
config.set_session_factory(session_factory)
```

Whereby I wanted to use beaker:

```
# Beaker cache
beaker.cache.regions = short_term, long_term
beaker.cache.type = memory
beaker.cache.short_term.expire = 3600
beaker.cache.long_term.expire = 86400

# Beaker sessions
beaker.session.type = redis
beaker.session.data_dir = %(here)s/data/sessions/data
beaker.session.lock_dir = %(here)s/data/sessions/lock
beaker.session.autor = true
#beaker.session.type = memory
beaker.session.key = dbas_prototyp
beaker.session.secret = ...
beaker.session.cookie_max_age = 3600
beaker.session.timeout = 3600
beaker.session.cookie_expires = true
beaker.session.url:127.0.0.1:4284
```

Did I missed something while setting up beaker?

Comment: CSRF token is a given by the session. How have you set up your sessions? How different workers share the session data?

Comment: Made an edit and added code, thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that I've found a first solution that works. I'm using beaker with an simple and external database like:

```
session.url = postgresql+psycopg2://user:password&@localhost:port/database?client_encoding=utf8

# Beaker cache
beaker.cache.regions = short_term, long_term
beaker.cache.type = ext:database
beaker.cache.short_term.expire = 3600
beaker.cache.long_term.expire = 86400
beaker.cache.extend_existing = True
beaker.cache.table_name = beaker_cache

beaker.session.type = ext:database
beaker.session.key = yyy
beaker.session.secret = xxx
beaker.session.cookie_max_age = 3600
beaker.session.timeout = 3600
beaker.session.cookie_expires = true
beaker.session.table_name = beaker_session
```

I'll post a solution with redis, after some other issues are fixed.

Answer (score 0):

`beaker.cache.type=memory` is in-process memory storage for session data (my guess). You are running two different processes and naturally they cannot see memory spaces of each other.

Use different Beaker backend or something like [pyramid_redis_session](https://github.com/ericrasmussen/pyramid_redis_sessions/) to share session data across processes (and servers).

Comment: Sounds logically correct. If i try a hotfix, where the cache type is set as a file, it won't work. I'll give redis a closer look and going to give feedback here.